# BackgroundWorker doesn't report progress when trying to send a loop of sms

Tags: c#, backgroundworker

I'm having a problem in using the BackgroundWorker while using a loop in sending sms, I want to return its progress in ProgressBar but I'm having an error "it doesn't report progress"

```
private void btnSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
     comm.Close();       
}

private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    for (int l = 0; l < 4; l++)
    {
        backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(l);
        i++;
    }
}

private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
     progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
}
```

Comment: Where is `backgroundWorker1` defined?

Comment: Since your values are going from 0..3 only, maybe it _is_ updating but you cannot see it because it is a too small amount to make it visible (the default maximum of the progress bar class is 100).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the `WorkerReportsProgress` property of the background worker to `true`.  This can be done in the designer via the Properties window.

Comment: thank you...
problem solve, my first time of using backgroundworker.

Comment: @ItsumoKokoro -- You're welcome.  I've used it many times and thus have forgotten to set that property many times.